# Sources for common laboratory Saccharomyces strains?

Tags: yeast

I'm used to working with bacteria - some of the more common laboratory strains sometimes come with an order from some vendors.  What's the most convenient source to order [common straings of Saccharomyces](http://wiki.yeastgenome.org/index.php/Commonly_used_strains) for lab work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Saccharomyces Genome Database* has a list of sources [here.](http://wiki.yeastgenome.org/index.php/Strains) One of them is the *Japanese Yeast Genetic Stock Center*: I checked their site out and found that they charge ¥390 per strain which is around USD4. There is also a USD5 fee on all orders. I searched for a couple of standard strains, and these were in the catalogue, so it looks like a good possibility.

(Incidentally I have used USD here rather than $ because there seems to be a bug when typing that symbol  twice in a post - try it and you'll see what I mean.)

Comment: thanks this looks good @AlanBoyd.  that's close enough to free for me!

Answer (score 2):

[ATCC](http://www.atcc.org/) is the place I would go to, just like purchasing cell lines or bacterial lines. The reference ATCC catalog numbers are also listed with each of the common strains you have linked. Depending on the purpose, you could just go to your local grocery store for baker's yeast.

Comment: ATCC costs $300 per sample.  When you work with e.coli some of the catalog give strains away free with a purchase.  hoping there is a similar tip for yeast...

Comment: Do they really charge that? They took over the Yeast Genetic Stock Center collection and as I recall the YGSC used to provide strains at a nominal price. My suggestion would be to contact the PI in a smaller/midsize lab and explain what you need. As long it is just a few strains I can't imagine that there would be a problem.

Comment: And that's exactly why people ask others for their cell lines to make their own stocks. ;) There are rare mamallian cell lines that ca cost tens of thousands of dollars from ATCC.

Answer (score 2):

One very important resource is EUROSCARF. http://web.uni-frankfurt.de/fb15/mikro/euroscarf/

It is one of the very famous and dedicated strain repository for yeast (S. cerevisiae) strains. You can even find some very useful yeast plasmids here.

Another resource I would recommend will be the original labs, which made the mutant strains/plasmids. Yeast researchers as a community are very nice, I have almost always obtained the strains and plasmids that requested from the original labs.

Hope it helps,
Cheers!!