# Where can I get yeast mutants?

Tags: molecular-biology

I want to use some yeast mutants to conduct gene functional analysis, and the gene was isolated from plants. Can anybody give me some information regarding the websites or agencies from which I can purchase the yeast mutants?

Comment: see this answer http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10917/sources-for-common-laboratory-saccharomyces-strains

Comment: as an addition to the above I'd add: the yeast deletion collection at Stanford http://www-sequence.stanford.edu/group/yeast_deletion_project/downloads.html#strainsavail  and this list of brewer's yeasts just for completeness: http://byo.com/resources/yeast