# Y285 Yeast Strain: Where to obtain from?

Tags: yeast

Often I see yeast strains mentioned like Y285 or Y301 etc. in papers. Is this some sort of universal notation? (Link to poster: https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/tfg/2014/119349/TFG_narcisferrerledo.pdf)

How does one go about locating such a strain to try in an experiment; are there repositories where you can get a strain from?

e.g. I tried searching the strains databases at Yeastgenome.org & DBVPG but these names ("Y285") don't produce any hits. Is there another canonical name I should be using to search them by?

http://wiki.yeastgenome.org/index.php/Strains

http://www.dbvpg.unipg.it/index.php/en/database

I even tried searching in the "National Collection of Yeast Cultures" but no luck. Any tips?

https://catalogue.ncyc.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=Y285

Edit:

Found this related thread on SE-Biology that gives links to other useful Repositories.

[Sources for common laboratory Saccharomyces strains?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10917/sources-for-common-laboratory-saccharomyces-strains?rq=1)

Am I just searching with the wrong name? Is it common to refer to Y285 by some other name?

Comment: Y285 or Y301 sound like specific mutants (at tyrosine 285/301 of a particular protein) but we can't really be sure without the paper you're referencing [and I'm not very familiar with yeast strain nomenclature]. Could you provide a paper link?

Comment: @Luigi Thanks. I've added the link to the source in the post: https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/tfg/2014/119349/TFG_narcisferrerledo.pdf